# Problem with zend_Controller_Router_Route

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-controller-router

I have a trouble with zend_controller_Router_Route.

I have created a route:

```
$router = $this->frontController->getRouter(); 
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route( 
   'catalog/:categoryIdent/:page',
       array( 'action' => 'index',
         'controller' => 'catalog', 
          'module' => 'storefront', 
          'categoryIdent' => '',
         'page' => 1 ), 
    array( 'categoryIdent' => '[a-zA-Z-_0-9]+', 
            'page' => '\d+' ) ); $router->addRoute('catalog_category', $route);
```

and this my view script:

```
 <div class="sub-nav">
  <h3>select <span>category</span></h3>
    <ul>
      <? foreach ($this->categories as $category): ?>
      <li><a href="<?=$this->url(array('categoryIdent' => $category->ident),   'catalog_category', true );?>"><?=$category->name; ?></a></li>
     <? endforeach; ?>
   </ul>
```

when i move mouse over a category, its href is exact (example :http://localhost/projectzend/chapter5/public/catalog/hats). But when i click, it return a url - http://localhost/

Where could be the problem?

Comment: what is happening when you visit http://localhost/projectzend/chapter5/public/catalog/hats directly in your browser?

Comment: do you have `throwExceptions(true)` called on you front-controller? I guess the route does not work correctly and that you don't get notified about that (due to disabled exceptions) and you just get redirected to the base-url.

Comment: what does your DOCUMENT_ROOT point to? www or projectzend/chapter5/public?